# How to get citations without round braces in beamer presentation?

Tags: tables, beamer, citing

I am making a beamer presentation where I would like to enter citation names in a table. I am using `cite{bibid}`. This is generating the citation inside round brackets which I would like to avoid.
My preamble is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{bookman}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usetheme{Singapore} 
\usecolortheme{beaver} 
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
\setbeamerfont{serif}{size=\large, series=\bfseries}
\AtBeginDocument{\usebeamerfont{structurebold}}
```

The table is

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{\huge Literature Survey}
    \justifying
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{||P{25mm} | p{8cm} ||}
        \hline
         Author & \hspace{25mm}Key Findings \\\hline
         \cite{kawamura1998state} & bla bla bla\\\hline
         \cite{waag2014critical} & bla bla bla\\\hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Triathlon results}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
```

MWEB as requested:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{filecontents}{\irbref.bib}
@inproceedings{kawamura1998state,
    title={State of {C}harge {E}stimation of {S}ealed {L}ead-{A}cid {B}atteries {U}sed for {E}lectric {V}ehicles},
    author={Kawamura, Atsuo and Yanagihara, Takahiro},
    booktitle={PESC 98 Record. 29th Annual IEEE Power Electronics Specialists Conference (Cat. No. 98CH36196)},
    volume={1},
    pages={pp. 583--587},
    month={22 May 1998},
    address={Fukuoka, Japan},
    year={1998},
    organization={IEEE}
}

@article{waag2014critical,
    title={Critical {R}eview of the {M}ethods for {M}onitoring of {L}ithium-ion {B}atteries in {E}lectric and {H}ybrid {V}ehicles,},
    author={Waag, Wladislaw and Fleischer, Christian and Sauer, Dek Uwe},
    journal={Journal of Power Sources,},
    volume={258},
    pages={pp. 321--339},
    year={2014},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{key}

\bibliographystyle{agsm3}
\bibliography{\irbref}

\end{document}
```

I edited the source code of default agsm package to get bold and italics to et al. and made the custom agsm3 style. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please prepare a complete [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that others can use to reproduce the same output you get.

Comment: In particular, do please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: Observe also that your query -- how to prevent a citation call-out from being surrounded by round parentheses -- is not directly related to the fact that happen to be using the `beamer` document class. If you think that I'm mistaken, i.e., that the query truly has a beamer-specific component, please show where I went wrong.

Comment: If I remember correctly,  the `agsm` bibliography style is introduced by the `harvard` package. According to its documentation, adding `\harvardparenthesis{none}` should help to remove the parentheses.

Comment: @Mico the query does truly have beamer specific component. I have used the same citations using cite and citep at  in report document class to get or remove the round parentheses.

Comment: @leandriis where am I supposed to put ```\harvardparenthesis{none}```? In the preamble

Comment: @TamoghnaBhattacharya - If you use `\citep` in a different document (say, one that uses the `report` document class), it must be the case that that document loads the `natbib` citation management package, as the `harvard` citation management package does not define `\citep`.

Comment: @Mico Precisely. I use ```\{natbib}``` in the other document to get ```\citep```. But ```natbib``` is not supported in beamer as far as I am concerned or am I missing something?

Comment: @TamoghnaBhattacharya - Who told you that `natbib` isn't supported by the `beamer` document class? That's just false.

Comment: @Mico whenever I run natbib, it raises a whole bunch of errors.

Comment: The solution by @leandriis worked out perfectly.

Comment: @TamoghnaBhattacharya - Please see the answer I just posted -- it employs both `beamer` and `natbib`, and it does *not* generate any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `natbib` citation management package works just fine with the `beamer` document class. For full compatibility with some of the bibliography styles -- such as `agsm` and `dcu` -- that are provided by the `harvard` citation management package, be sure to load `har2nat` as well. (This piece of advice is *not* specific to `beamer`.)

I would use `\cite` and `\citep` to create citation call-outs *with* parentheses and `\citealp` to create citation call-outs *without* parentheses.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{natbib,har2nat}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}} % optional
\bibliographystyle{dcu} % or some other suitable bib style

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{smith:01,author="Sam Smith",title="Thoughts",year=3001}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\cite{smith:01}, \citep{smith:01}, \citealp{smith:01}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I keep getting \citename already defined. \newcommand\citename{}. Just can't get around it. And things are getting increasingly weirder, I have 2 consecutive frames with citations, in the first one I am not getting 'et al.' format but on the second one I am getting it. There is no difference in the syntax amongst the 2 frames.

Comment: @TamoghnaBhattacharya - What are you trying to achieve by `\newcommand\citename{}`; why aren't you running `\renewcommand\citename{}`? Why are you trying to undefine `\citename` at all? (Sadly, but maybe not surprisingly, my divination skills are just rubbish.) The formatting issue that appears to be bugging you -- all authors listed the first time a piece is cited, first-author-et-al from the second time onward -- could be caused by you loading `natbib` with the option `longnamesfirst`. Is that the case? Please do provide more usable information about your document setup.

Comment: @TamoghnaBhattacharya - Note also that if a version of `agsm` is in use, the issue of getting a full list of authors in the first citation call-out and first-author-et-al the second time the piece is cited arises both if the `harvard` package is loaded and you use `\cite` to create citation call-outs (along with `\harvardparenthesis{none}` in the preamble) and if the `natbib` package is loaded with the option `longnamesfirst` and if you use `\citealp` to create citation call-outs. If you want et-al type citiation call-outs throughout, do *not* specify `longnamesfirst`.